# Running Joomla with Nginx

Tags: nginx, joomla

I want to run multiple joomla site on a web server running nginx. I have access to the configuration files. Right now I have one configuration file for each site I run, looking like this:

```
 server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.myjoomlasite.com
    server_name_in_redirect off;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.access_log main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.error_log info;

    root /var/www/domain;
    index index.php;
    # Support Clean (aka Search Engine Friendly) URLs
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    index index.php index.html index.htm default.html default.htm;
    # deny running scripts inside writable directories
    location ~* /(images|cache|media|logs|tmp)/.*\.(php|pl|py|jsp|asp|sh|cgi)$ {
            return 403;
            error_page 403 /403_error.html;
    }

    location ~ .*.php$ {
        include /opt/nginx/conf/fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    # caching of files
    location ~* \.(ico|pdf|flv)$ {
            expires 1y;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|swf|xml|txt)$ {
            expires 14d;
    }
```

}

The above configuration works well, and when I hit www.domain.com woth my browser, my site appears.

What I want is to be able to write www.myserver.com/myjoomlasite and also see my site.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a rewrite statement or root. The latter is the easiest:

```
location /page/ {
    root /my/absolute/path/library/content/folder/country;
}
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: yes I can be :)

Comment: Sorry, this does not do what I want.

Comment: Maybe you should clearly state what you want first :)

Answer (score 0):

add "www.myserver.com" to your server_name line, also do what the above answer suggested (rewritten to be a little more relevant to your request).

```
location /joomlasite/ {
    root /path/to/your/joomla/root;
}
```

This will make your site available at 4 urls:

- www.myjoomlasite.com
- www.myjoomlasite.com/joomlasite/
- www.myserver.com
- www.myserver.com/joomlasite/